# Elastic Collision Point Masses / Hard Spheres:: Proof that Magnitude of Relative Velocity is Unchanged

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, collision, boltzmann-equation

## Statement of the Problem

On our way to the Boltzmann Collision integral, we consider the perfectly elastic collision of two point-masses with identical mass. The velocities prior collision are denoted with $\boldsymbol{c}_1, \boldsymbol{c}_2$ and post-collision with $\boldsymbol{c}'_1, \boldsymbol{c}'_2$.

The impact is assumed perfectly elastic, i.e., moment and kinetic energy are conserved. For a normalized mass $m = 1$ this reads
\begin{align} \boldsymbol{c}_1 + \boldsymbol{c}_2 &= \boldsymbol{c}'_1 + \boldsymbol{c}'_2 \tag{1}\\
\Vert \boldsymbol{c}_1 \Vert_2^2 + \Vert \boldsymbol{c}_2 \Vert_2^2 &= \Vert \boldsymbol{c}'_1 \Vert_2^2 + \Vert \boldsymbol{c}'_2 \Vert_2^2 \tag{2} \end{align}

We introduced two more quantities: The center of mass velocity $$\boldsymbol{G} = \frac{\boldsymbol{c}_1 + \boldsymbol{c}_2}{2}, \quad \boldsymbol{G}' = \frac{\boldsymbol{c}'_1 + \boldsymbol{c}'_2}{2} $$
It is clear that Eq. $(1)$ implies that $\boldsymbol{G} = \boldsymbol{G}'$.

However, we also introduced the magnitude of the relative velocity
$$g_{21} = \Vert \boldsymbol{c}_2 - \boldsymbol{c}_1 \Vert_2, \quad g_{21}' = \Vert \boldsymbol{c}'_2 - \boldsymbol{c}'_1 \Vert_2$$
Which is by Eq. (2) claimed to remain the same throughout the collision, i.e.,
$$g_{21} \overset{!}{=}g_{21}'$$

## My attempt:

\begin{align}g_{21}^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^3 (c_{2,i} - c_{1, i} )^2 = \sum_{i=1}^3 c_{2,i}^2 - 2 c_{1,i}c_{2,i} + c_{1,i}^2 \\
&= \Vert \boldsymbol{c}_2 \Vert_2^2 + \Vert \boldsymbol{c}_1 \Vert_2^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{1,i}c_{2,i} \\
&\overset{(2)}{=} \Vert \boldsymbol{c}'_2 \Vert_2^2 + \Vert \boldsymbol{c}'_1 \Vert_2^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^3 c_{1,i}c_{2,i} \\
&= \big(g_{21}'\big)^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^3 c'_{1,i}c'_{2,i}  -c_{1,i}c_{2,i}\end{align}

This is where I am pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Eq. $(1)$

$$c_1 + c_2 = c_1'+c_2'$$

gives

$$(c_1+c_2)^2=c_1^2+c_2^2 + 2c_1c_2=c_1'^2+c_2'^2+2c_1'c_2' = (c_1'+c_2')^2.$$

Using Eq. $(2)$ yields

$$2c_1c_2=2c_1'c_2',$$

and thus, using your calculation, we have

$$g_{21}^2=c_1'^2+c_2'^2 - 2c_1c_2 = c_1'^2+c_2'^2-2c_1'c_2' = (c_1'-c_2')^2 = g_{21}'^2$$